# Why the file contains only Line1

Tags: java, file, filewriter, printwriter

the Generated y.txt only contains line1 why does line 2 is abcent

```
public class Writer{    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("y.txt"));
            PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(fw);
            pw1.println ("line1 ");
            pw1.close();
            PrintWriter pw2 = new PrintWriter(fw);
            pw2.println("line2 ");
            pw2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `pw1.close()` calls `fw.close()`.

Comment: ya u right
i moved pw1.close() down an it worked
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you close  the PrintWriter, the file is closed.

The Javadocs for `PrintWriter.close()` state: "Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect."

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two PrintWriters, it is unnecessary.  You should only use one PrintWriter for the whole file

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("y.txt"));
    PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(fw);

    pw1.println ("line1 ");
    pw1.println("line2 ");

    pw1.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for [close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close()), we can see that calling close

"*Closes the stream and releases **any system resources associated with it***"

This includes your FileWriter `fw`, so, when you try to initialize pw2 with fw, the resource fw is already closed because of calling `close()` on pw1.

Answer (score 0):

> public void close()
>   Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it. **Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.**

Because you closed pw1, the first instance of PrintWriter it closes all instances of within that frame.

[Java Doc's for Print Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close())

happy coding!

Whoops didn't see that this has already been answered!